# Are tool questions on topic here?

Tags: support

I have a question about [PBS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Batch_System).  (Can I qsub more jobs from within a job script, or how can I start many processes and distribute them across nodes from within a job script?)  Are such questions (about computational tools we use) on topic here?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, especially tool topics that are specific to high performance computing environments.

Comment: Alright, I'll post my question on the main site then.  Hope it's not too basic.  I already wasted two hours on it.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely; tools specific to scientific computation are definitely on topic. We already have a question on PBS as well: [Prolonging PBS job](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/112/276).

Comment: Thanks, posted: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/1084/605